# Opening MiKTeX and the Source and Preview Windows Split but do not Fully Cover the Screen (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, display

I've used MiKTeX/TeXworks on many machines, but this is the first time I've had this problem. When I open a standard .tex file, the source window appears on the left and the preview appears on the right. However, unlike on other machines, they do not fully occupy the left and right sides of the screen. There is extra room to the two sides, on the bottom (above the taskbar), and in between the windows. See picture below for an example:

[Sample screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2n7b.png)

This is far more annoying/distracting than I expected. I've used the "Windows Key" + "Left Arrow" work around for a few months, but I'm sick of doing so. Is there any way to change the default so that it opens in a way that fully covers the screen (excluding the task bar)?

I'm running MiKTeX v2.9.6500 and Windows 10 Home. Thanks!

Comment: Wrong site, I'm afraid. You're looking for [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions.

Comment: @Ken White – Sorry! I'll move over there and post it. Thanks for the heads up!